# PCA for dimensionality reduction with simultaneous clustering

Tags: clustering, pca

so, let's say I have a set of 3D points. Let's say these points lie more or less on a plane that is embedded in the 3d space, then I can use PCA to 'compress' these 3D points to 2D coordinates on that plane, such that they still aproximate the original data well.

let's say half of the 3d points don't lie close to that plane, but instead close to some other plane.

If I just do PCA and reduce to 2 dimensions, I won't get a good aproximation.

If the algorithm however would 'see' that some of the 3d points compress well onto one plane, and others compress well on another plane and label each point and do PCA separately for each set (and compress them to points with 2 coordinates plus one bit that says which set it belongs to) it will aproximate the original data much better.

What's the name for such a PCA algorithm that is also capable of splitting the input data into maximally N sets (probably with some penalty on the number of sets), such that for each set dimensionality reduction yields a much better fitting than if all data points would be reduced together?

// Edit:
adding an example. If one would only cluster by distance in the high-dim space one would arrive at the bad clustering where there are more clusters and each cluster would have a higher error when projected down.

the good example uses fewer clusters and they project better on their 2 dimensional sub-spaces (the green cluster being able to even compress to a 1D space)

[image]

Comment: "*If I just do PCA and reduce to 2 dimensions, I won't get a good aproximation.*" this is not so, you will get two different clusters of 2d points

Comment: its called clustering (by some clustring algorithm) the features from PCA

Comment: Technically this doesn't really reduce the dimensionality since you still have 3 dimensions at the end, it only makes the 3rd dimension a binary categorical feature representing whether the point belongs to cluster 1 or 2.

Comment: @Erwan in this example yes, but let's say you reduce from 1000 dimensions to 50 dimensions with 10 different clusters, then you have 51 dimensional points (of which one dimension is an index into the 10 clusters)

Comment: @NikosM. how? note that I do not know which points belong to which cluster initially (or how many clusters there are at all for which it makes sense to cluster them)

Comment: @user1282931, clustering is unsupervised, no need to know beforehand the class of each datum. Furthermore one can do clustering on any data (as long as one can define a notion of distance), so one can cluster the original data, or the PCA features of the data by the same token

Comment: @Nikos M. that's clear - but for this you need to be able to define the notion of distance in the high-dim space and for this you need to already know in what way the data might be clustered.
What I'm looking for is a clustering such that the error is minimized if it is defined in the following way: E = sum of least squares between original points and compressed points backprojected into high-dem space (each according to the basis of their cluster) + C * number of clusters (since it's clear that the error would be zero if each point would be its own cluster)

Comment: @NikosM. I added an animation as example. If one would simply cluster by the distance in the high-dim space, one would arrive at the Bad clustering in which there are more clusters that also compress worse (the green and red clusters in the bad example will have a high error when projecting onto a 2D space). Whereas in the good example there are fewer clusters, two of which can project well onto a 2D subspace and one (the green one) can even project well onto a 1D space

Answer (score 2):

Your task is achieved by [Subspace Clustering](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.1005.pdf)

Comment: This indeed seems to be what I'm looking for - thank you!